# Angular JS - Selecting An Option Generated By Ng-Options Within An Ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to build an online cart/store in Angular but am having trouble with having people being able to select how many of each item they want.

The ng-options works and the default is set correctly using ng-model. It's in an ng-repeat. But for some reason the first time I pick any option in the `<select>` every `<select>` option (default) gets wiped. Why does this behavior occur? I've made a plunk so you can see what I mean.

**http://plnkr.co/edit/6CM0frKnhuzvfu52H9GZ?p=preview**

**Code**

HTML:

```
<body id="page-top" class="is-loading" ng-controller="bCtrl">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in breads | groupBy: 'Type'">
      <label class="itemTitle">{{key}}</label>
      <div ng-repeat="bread in value">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">{{bread.Name}}</label>
        <select name="@{{bread.Name}} quantity" ng-options="quantity as quantityOption.value for quantityOption in quantityOptions track by quantityOption.value" ng-model="selection.selected"></select>
        <p class="price">{{bread.Price|currency}} {{bread.details}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var app = angular.module('fook', ['angular.filter']);
app.controller('bCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
$scope.breads = [{"id":19,"Name":"Apple Pie","Type":"Pies","Picture":"","Price":"3.95","PriceWholesale":"23.95","DaysNotAvailable":"","TwoBuisnessDays":"True","canShip":"False","minAmount":0,"details":"","weight":"","holiday":"Thanksgiving","quantity":0,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},{"id":20,"Name":"Old Fashioned Pumpkin Pie","Type":"Pies","Picture":"","Price":"14.95","PriceWholesale":"14.95","DaysNotAvailable":"","TwoBuisnessDays":"True","canShip":"False","minAmount":0,"details":"","weight":"","holiday":"Thanksgiving","quantity":0,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},{"id":21,"Name":"Peasant White Rolls","Type":"Rolls","Picture":"","Price":"4.95","PriceWholesale":"4.95","DaysNotAvailable":"","TwoBuisnessDays":"True","canShip":"False","minAmount":0,"details":"per 1\/2 dozen.","weight":"","holiday":"Thanksgiving","quantity":0,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},{"id":22,"Name":"Honey Whole Wheat Rolls","Type":"Rolls","Picture":"","Price":"4.95","PriceWholesale":"4.95","DaysNotAvailable":"","TwoBuisnessDays":"True","canShip":"False","minAmount":0,"details":"per 1\/2 dozen.","weight":"","holiday":"Thanksgiving","quantity":0,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},{"id":23,"Name":"Corn Rolls","Type":"Rolls","Picture":"","Price":"4.95","PriceWholesale":"4.95","DaysNotAvailable":"","TwoBuisnessDays":"True","canShip":"False","minAmount":0,"details":"per 1\/2 dozen.","weight":"","holiday":"Thanksgiving","quantity":0,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},{"id":24,"Name":"Cranberry Orange Rolls","Type":"Rolls","Picture":"","Price":"4.95","PriceWholesale":"4.95","DaysNotAvailable":"","TwoBuisnessDays":"True","canShip":"False","minAmount":0,"details":"per 1\/2 dozen.","weight":"","holiday":"Thanksgiving","quantity":0,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},{"id":25,"Name":"Cranberry Orange Roll Wreath","Type":"Roll Wreaths","Picture":"","Price":"20","PriceWholesale":"20","DaysNotAvailable":"","TwoBuisnessDays":"True","canShip":"False","minAmount":0,"details":"","weight":"","holiday":"Thanksgiving","quantity":0,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},{"id":26,"Name":"Peasant White Roll Wreath","Type":"Roll Wreaths","Picture":"","Price":"18","PriceWholesale":"18","DaysNotAvailable":"","TwoBuisnessDays":"True","canShip":"False","minAmount":0,"details":"","weight":"","holiday":"Thanksgiving","quantity":0,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},{"id":27,"Name":"Honey Whole Wheat Roll Wreath","Type":"Roll Wreaths","Picture":"","Price":"18","PriceWholesale":"18","DaysNotAvailable":"","TwoBuisnessDays":"True","canShip":"False","minAmount":0,"details":"","weight":"","holiday":"Thanksgiving","quantity":0,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}]
$scope.selection={};
$scope.quantityOptions = [
    { value: 0 },
    { value: 1 },
    { value: 2 },
    { value: 3 },
    { value: 4 },
    { value: 5 },
    { value: 6 },
    { value: 7 },
    { value: 8 },
    { value: 9 },
    { value: 10 }
  ];
$scope.selection.selected=$scope.quantityOptions[0];
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is fine, using *track by* and object for *ng-model* in your case is correct, just change quantity to quantityOption in your *ng-options*:

```
ng-options="quantityOption as quantityOption.value for quantityOption in quantityOptions track by quantityOption.value"
```

otherwise, selection.selected will be assigned quantity variable, which is undefined

Comment: When I make this change every select value is modified when one is. How do I modify the ng-model so each item can have an individual quantity?

Comment: see your modified plunker for possible solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/MICe83PwtUqKiMgszzqI?p=preview.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in a public fork of your plunker, seemed to fix it. You were doing some funky stuff in that select element declaration and the $scope. This way they all start as 0, and changing one doesn't change the others.

```
// Change these lines in your script
...
$scope.selected={};
...
$scope.selected=$scope.quantityOptions[0];

// Change this select element declaration
<select name="@{{bread.Name}} quantity" 
        ng-options="option as option.value for option in quantityOptions" 
        ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
   <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"></select>
   <p>{{selectedName | json}}</p>
</div>

app.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.items = [
     { id: 1, name: 'Yes' },
     { id: 2, name: 'No' },
     { id: 3, name: 'Might be' }
   ];
});
```

Just for your reference how ng-model works & Select using angular.

1. The above will allow you to select an entire object into 2. $scope.selectedName directly.

2.With Angular, you don't need to worry about what's in your option tag. Let Angular handle that, you should only care about what's in your **model** in your scope.